# How to resolve the "Version history cannot be accessed at this time because server is busy. Please try again later" message?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I made some modifications in a page a using SPDesigner 2013. When I try to open the page I get an error, so I want to revert back to a previous version. When I try to go back to a previous version in SharePoint Designer, however, I get the error:

> Versions cannot be accessed at this time because server is busy .Please try again later.

How can I fix this and/or access my version history to restore a previous version of my page?

Comment: Yep I am having the same issue. Has anyone checked the SPD 2013 updates to see if it is fixed described in any of them. I am using SPD x86 as this the version of office I was given by my client. Let me know what you discover

Answer (score 2):

I am able to revert back to previous version in browser but not using sharepoint designer.Go to SiteActions--->Site contents --->Pages--->your page(click on ellipsis button)---Version History.You can revert back to the desired version.I attached an image for reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this error in SharePoint Designer by checking out the file and then clicking on the file name to go to the Page Summary view:

[image: SP Designer 2013 Page Summary view]

From there, you can select a prior version to restore:

[image: SP Designer 2013 list of prior versions]